# Javascript variable to PHP variable - Post if statement isnt working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

my `if(isset($_POST['height'])){` is just going straight to `else{}` what is the reason for this?. so basically it's suppose to detect the height of a div. Send it back to the PHP where it is compared to 1 and echo different statements depending on the product. I am wanting to keep it AJAX so that I am able to do detect the height of a div and send it to a PHP if statement without having to refresh the page. if you have any idea what's going on it would be much appreciated. papa bless.

**PHP**

```
       <?php

    if(isset($_POST['height'])){
        $solo_height = $_POST['height'];

        if ($solo_height > 1){
            //HERE YOU SHOULD ECHO BACK A RESPONSE TO THE AJAX CALL                  
            echo '<div class="view_full_post">View Full Post</div>';
            // WHAT DOES $this->output($var); DO??? I HAVE NO CLUE...
            // SO JUST ECHO THE DIV JUST FOR TESTING...
        }else{
            echo "The Height is Less than a Thousand... What do we do sir???";
        }
    }
?>
```

Ajax

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            view_height = $("#view_height").height();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",  // POINTS TO THE PROCESSING FILE WE CREATED ABOVE
                data:{ height: view_height },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(view_height);      // NOW YOU SHOULD BE ABLE TO GET A RESPONSE....
                    // UPDATE THE DIV THAT YOU WANTED TO...
                    // ==> HERE IS THE NEW UPDATE REFLECTING YOUR USE CASE:
                    // ==> ADD THE DIV RIGHT AT THE TOP OF THE BODY ELEMENT...
                },              

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('The following error occured: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);
                },

                complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    console.log('The Request Round-Trip has successfully Completed... Happy Coding....');                   
                }
            });

        });
    })(jQuery);

        </script>
```

Comment: print var_dump($_POST); in your index.php file.

Comment: use `!empty` instead of `isset`

Comment: Write $(function() { ..... ... }); instead of (function ($) { ....  })(jQuery);

Comment: None of these worked :/ Thanks though

Comment: what you got in a console??

Comment: what is the name of the file where the ajax script is?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef a 10 which is the height of the div and 'The Request Round-Trip has successfully Completed.'

Comment: The ajax script and the php script are in the same file it is called index.php

Comment: `console.log(data);`  instead of  `console.log(view_height); `and check to output...

Comment: @LittleSauce separe the two man

Comment: your ajax works corectly you don't know how ajax works that is why you say the php returns only the else message

Comment: It outputs the whole index.php form <html> to </html>

Comment: @LittleSauce of course it outputs the whole page , move the php in a new file

Comment: @LittleSauce Move the php at the top of file and use  `die();` at the end of php script

Comment: @ManjeetBarnala didn't work :/

Comment: @madalinivascu how do I separate the 2 ?

Comment: its a function on your operating sistem called new file, you click that and you create a new file,then you use a combination a copy/paste to move the php from one file to another, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 files in the same directory

file1.php

```
     <?php

    if(isset($_POST['height'])){
        $solo_height = $_POST['height'];

        if ($solo_height > 1){
            echo '<div class="view_full_post">View Full Post</div>';
        }else{
            echo "The Height is Less than a Thousand... What do we do sir???";
        }
    }
?>
```

index.php (with the html, body tag,etc)

```
.....
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            view_height = $("#view_height").height();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "file1.php",  // POINTS TO THE PROCESSING FILE WE CREATED ABOVE
                data:{ height: view_height },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(view_height); 
                    $('body').append('<h1>'+data+'</h1>');
                },              

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('The following error occured: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);
                },

                complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    console.log('The Request Round-Trip has successfully Completed... Happy Coding....');                   
                }
            });

        });
        </script>
....
```

Comment: OMG THANKS SO MUCH MAN ILY

Comment: @LittleSauce when you do ajax alway have 2 files ,oen with the ajax script and one with the php script to return data to it

Comment: didn't recognize he had just one file